# How to Encrypt & Decrypt whole URL or URL parameters in mvc3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, encryption

```
return RedirectToAction("deshboardportal", "Portal",new { User_Id = Session["USER_ID"], RoleId = Session["ROLE_ID"]});
```

In this above code i want to only encrypt url parameter which is written below :-

```
new { User_Id = Session["USER_ID"], RoleId = Session["ROLE_ID"]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can try

```
 return RedirectToAction("deshboardportal", "Portal", new { User_Id = Encode(Session["USER_ID"].ToString()), RoleId = Encode(Session["ROLE_ID"].ToString()) });



  public string Encode(string encodeMe)
        {
            byte[] encoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodeMe);
            return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);
        }

        public static string Decode(string decodeMe)
        {
            byte[] encoded = Convert.FromBase64String(decodeMe);
            return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encoded);
        }
```